# Does React useMemo Re-render if Dependent Object is An Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a useMemo which needs to be re-rendered base on `currentSettings.Filters`, which is an array.

```js
  let [currentSettings, setSettings] = useState(QuerySettings);
  let settings_Sales = useMemo(()=>{ 
    let s = Object.assign({}, currentSettings)
    s.XFieldName = "ProductName";
    s.YFieldName = "Sales";
    return s;
  }, [currentSettings.Filters])
```

my object QuerySettings, the initial value of `currentSettings` looks like this:

```js
const QuerySettings = {
    "XFieldName": "ProductName",
    "YFieldName": "Counts",
    "Filters": {
        "ProductGroup": [],
        "ProductName": [],
    }
}
```

Now, when the user select off a form for products they want to filter, i.e.

```js
  function handleChange(e, fieldName, settings) { 
    let settings_temp = {...settings};
    settings_temp.Filters[fieldName] = Array.from(e.currentTarget.selectedOptions, (v)=> v.value)
    setSettings(settings_temp)
  }
```

My `currentSettings` will look like this:

```
{
    "XFieldName": "ProductName",
    "YFieldName": "Counts",
    "Filters": {
        "ProductGroup": [],
        "ProductName": ["ProductA", "ProductB"],
    }
}
```

But my useMemo part does not get re-rendered. Is it because my Filter is an array and React can't detect changes in an Array? Also, feel free to refactor my code, I'm definitely trying to learn how to code better.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks the comments and solution. Just a note that the reason it's depending on `currentSettings.Filters` (instead of `currentSettings`) is that we wish to avoid a re-render if other objects in currentSettings (i.e. XFieldName) changes. In other words, re-render *if and only if* `currentSettings.Filters` changes.

Comment: Arrays/objects as dependencies will often cause this. There are packages that do deep compares, using `JSON.stringify(anArray)` is one *possible* workaround but not always a good idea. If you search the web for something like "react useeffect dependency object array" or something you'll get multiple techniques.

Comment: wouldn't a dependency of `[currentSettings]` work?

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't know that the data has updated so it won't rerender.  You can try and use a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) instead of memo.  With a proper dependency it will let React know the state has changed.

```
  const defaultSettings = {
    XFieldName: 'ProductName',
    YFieldName: 'Counts',
    Filters: {
      ProductGroup: [],
      ProductName: [],
    },
  };

  const [currentSettings, setSettings] = useState(defaultSettings);

  const defineFilters = useCallback(
    (newSettings) => {
      setSettings((currentSettings) => ({
        ...currentSettings,
        ...newSettings,
      }));
    },
    [setSettings]
  );

  function handleChange(e, fieldName, settings) {
    //settings_temp.Filters[fieldName] = Array.from(e.currentTarget.selectedOptions, (v)=> v.value) // don't know what this does
    defineFilters(settings); // assuming your settings is in {xFieldName:'', YFieldName: ''} format
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If I understand the logic right,  the change of `XFieldName` and `YFieldName` will also cause a re-render (due to dependency on [setSettings])? I guess the subtle point is can we re-render only when Filter changes, but not when XFieldName and YFieldName changes?

Comment: Yes, it currently will do that if you only pass defineFilters({filters: {new filters}}). If you update any of the values it will re-render.  To prevent this, you should only group states that change together.  If you need to modify x & y independently from filters you should separate their states.  i.e. filterState and fieldNameState.  This way it would only rerender when needed.